# show message using sharedWorker in all tabs

Tags: jquery, shared-worker

I'd like to show in all tabs a message.
So I'm using sharedWorker for this:

```
//sharedworker

var worker = new SharedWorker('/js/realtime.js');
worker.port.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
}, false);

worker.port.start();

// post a message to the shared web worker
worker.port.postMessage("name");
```

and the realtime.js:

```
var connections = 0; // count active connections

self.addEventListener("connect", function (e) {

    var port = e.ports[0];
    connections++;

    port.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
        port.postMessage("Hello " + e.data + " (port #" + connections + ")");
    }, true);

    port.start();

}, true);
```

I'd like to see the alert in all tabs of my browser, but it is only in one... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your `port` variable refers to a single tab. Each time the "connect" event fires, you get another port connected to another tab. So if you want to send a message to all tabs, you need to store all the ports and then send the message to all of them. Something like this:

```
const ports = [];

self.addEventListener("connect", function (e) {
    ports.push(e.ports[0]);

    port.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
            ports[i].postMessage("Hello " + e.data + " (port #" + i + ")");
        }
    }, true);

    port.start();

}, true);
```

Alternatively, [I wrote a library](https://github.com/dumbmatter/promise-worker-bi#shared-workers) which lets you easily send messages between a shared worker and tabs - either sending a message directly to one tab, or broadcasting to all connected tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The latest news, you can use BroadcastChannel in SharedWorker to achieve

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.